# How to perform reliable performance tests in a parallel architecture?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing

I am developing data structures and algorithms in the realm of computation geometry. It is very important for me to be able to **compare the running time of two algorithms** reliably.

The problem is that when I run an algorithm and it runs for 30 minutes I cannot say that those 30 minutes were spent on executing the algorithm and not on playing mp3s.

I have an Intel® Core™ i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz × 8 processor computer running Ubuntu 13.04. All my programs are written in C++ and use only libraries written in either C or C++.

1. Does this mean that I can safely run let's say 6 experiments in parallel, while the OS will use the other 2 for its own business?
2. Should I run the experiments as 6 threads of one program, or make 6 different executables and run those?
3. What is the difference between those two approaches?

Comment: You run them one at a time - with nothing else in the background.

Comment: *How* do you measure the time now?

Comment: Also, you might want to look at the [`time`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time) command.

Comment: @Joachim I make 6 separate executables and run them all at once. I check the system monitor tool from time to time to check that there is at least one processor with less than 100% load.

Comment: @Mystical Is there a reason for not running them in parallel? Are not all 8 cores the same? Even when I run only one experiment I can see that the OS is passing it from one core to another from time to time.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik No they are not the same. 1) Your processor only has 4 cores, not 8. Two threads share the same core. 2) All the cores share the same memory bandwidth. 3) They all share the same power management.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want consistent results, running a single benchmark at a time will improve the chances of that - because the different tasks are more likely to:

1. Move from one CPU to another (thus making whatever has been loaded into the cache less meaningful).
2. Cause memory bandwidth and cache pressure that causes interference with another process.

If you are running the benchmark at the same time as playing MP3's, downloading blockbuster feature length films, etc, then you won't know if that is indeed interfering (or how much it is interfering) with your CPU intensive tasks - you can, probably tell the other way around, if the music starts getting choppy, or the download times out ... ;) As with running multiple tasks in parallel, the cache and moving from processor to processor core will be the most important effects.

You may find that if you run one set of benchmarks "with everything on" and another set of benchmarks "with everything off", that it makes no difference. But you may also find that it does make a difference.

The same applies to running one or multiple benchmarks. Try running 6 in parallel, and compare the time each benchmark itself takes when run with nothing else running.

**You only know that by comparing the different cases.**

If it makes no difference you can keep playing music, download the latest blockbuster film, etc whilst benchmarking, because you know that the 0.01% difference that makes is not important to the overall performance of the application.

From experience, I've found that it usually doesn't make much of a difference if you run a bunch of other "light" things in the background, but it will increase the amount of variation from one run to another. Again, if the benchmark runs for half an hour, it may not matter - after all, you will probably have enough variation in that runtime from one run to another, simply from the general things that vary in a CPU and in the OS, purely by "things don't happen EXACTLY the same every time" factors, that it won't make enough difference.

If you are doing small optimisations, such as toggling compiler options that give 0.5% difference in the result, but the difference between runs is 1%, then you need to run several runs to show the actual difference, and the more interference from other processes, the more chances are that you won't be able to measure small changes. Sometimes, many small changes together can make a notable difference (e.g. if you move a function F1 to allow it to be inlined , and then do the same to function F2, together they amount to 1% improvement, but individually it wasn't measurable, because it was hidden in the noise). The bigger the noise is, the more likely you are to "miss out" on some small but ultimately beneficial changes.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough and detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

First of all: The Intel i7-2600 has 4 "true" cores, but each core can run two threads in parallel. This "hyperthreading" is faster than traditional threading via preemption by the OS scheduler. Because  execution can continue on the other thread, if one thread has to wait a short time (like when reading a value from main memory after a cache miss) hyperthreading tends to increase throughput a bit. So the combined performance of two processes running on a hyperthreaded core is typically 10% to 20% higher than the performance of a single process running on the same core. In case of high cache pressure, the combined performance can be worse, though.

But, more important for your performance timing needs: If two threads on one core have a combined performance of 120%, it means, that the single thread performance drops to 60%!

As far, as I know, the linux kernel scheduler is aware of hyperthreading, so it will try to keep the second thread on each core idle, if the first thread is doing heavy work, and if there are still cores available. So, if you start only 3 timing processes in parallel and leave one core for your desktop, and don't do much side work (like compiling etc.), then you should get rather consistent timing data! If you start 4 processes, make sure, the desktop is really idle. If you start 5 processes or more, expect inconsistent timing results due to hyperthreading.

If you use time on the shell to time your commands, the reported user and system time tend to be more accurate than the total time. This is because the OS counts as user and system time only that time, that the process was actually running in userland or the system, respectively. If your code does not do much I/O, system time should be low and the user time should be close to the total running time.